# The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm getting following error when tried to create topic for amazon sns :

> The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service (Service:
>   AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: OptInRequired; Request ID:
>   4b507354-d0ff-5769-aa80-3c296a6c7f7d)

I've also created IAM user and subscribed for the SNS service but getting same result every time.

Comment: This helps https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-access-service/

Answer (score 39):

It takes a while to AWS to verify your card details after you register a new account with AWS. It would be great if AWS would give a more sensible message,

Comment: This can also happen if you have no credit card registered.    Having an AWS FAQ covering this would be good too.

Comment: now there's a help page about this error  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-access-service/

Answer (score 23):

In my case, Account verification was not completed.

complete the account registrations or verification process by going to

[Link](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup?type=resubscribe#/resubscribed)

Comment: The same solution.

Comment: looks like it takes some hours to reflect on their 'data store host' ... once i just completed , it is not working after 30 minutes

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. After I verified my mobile phone number using their automatic call process, this error message went away.

Answer (score 2):

You need three things for this error to be gone, as explained here: https://pagespeedpro.com/cloudfront-origin-pull-configuration/

1. verify your phone number
2. verify your payment method
3. select a support subscription (free or other)

You can do them by going to this link: https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup?type=resubscribe#/resubscribed

Answer (score 1):

you can check your account status and all sign-up process are completed 
https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/console/signup?region=us-east-2

Answer (score 0):

In my case, its Caused by security issues,  When I created a new key pair, After password verification is completed,The problem is solved