# The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service : AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: OptInRequired

Tags: amazon-sns

I am creating Platform Application for that I am providing following details:

Application Name = "TestNotification"

Push Application Platform = Apple Development

Push Certificate Type = iOS Push Certificate

Choosing P12 file

Loading Credential from file

Certificate Key

Private Key

And Finally Clicking on Create Platform Application

But I am getting following error:

The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: OptInRequired; Request ID: a0b89f4e-f34b-51f2-b4ae-ce136d8b1fe1).

I google out but not able to solve the issue.. Please help.

Comment: check this ***OptInRequired***

Comment: How and where can we check that? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427376/the-aws-access-key-id-needs-a-subscription-for-the-service

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Account verification was not completed.

complete the account registrations or varication process by going to

[https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup?type=resubscribe#/resubscribed.](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup?type=resubscribe#/resubscribed)