# Amazon Free-Tier, asking for Opt-In to RDS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Hi recently(today) I joined the Amazon Web Services platform, to host my database in the cloud, however after creating an account(free tier), when I navigated to the create database(RDS), I noticed this error:

> The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: OptInRequired; Request ID: a27f4e40-5687-43b3-8bba-ccf419cf7e8f)

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Isn't it the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427376/the-aws-access-key-id-needs-a-subscription-for-the-service) one?

Comment: Just wait a while and try again. It can take a while for an account to setup. Also, please note that the [Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is a billing discount for a certain amount of usage. It does not mean that the Account itself is free.

Comment: Checking back 12 hours later... is it working for you now?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-access-service/)

> If you're using an account that was created in or after 2011, then [update your account status](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup?type=resubscribe#/resubscribed).

Comment: In which case you'll need to raise with AWS support